# How to Delete Virtual Directory in Mac Terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I tried removing virtual directory named virtualenvs that i created for a Django project using **rmdir ~/.virtualenvs** but its not working properly , i want to delete whole virtual directory so that i can setup new one and can remove old project that are saved in virtualenvs folder. I am attaching the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Firstly, don't post text as screenshots; secondly, this is not a question about programming and therefore is off-topic for SO.

Comment: This is not a "How 2 Unix" site. This is a site for problems with *code* (or tools used by and large to produce code), and "how do I delete a non-empty directory" doesn't fall under that. Also, try Googling your error message when you try `rmdir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rm -rf` to remove a directory and all its contents:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked for that moment but when i reopen the terminal it reappears, might be its because of Virtualenvwrapper , let me uninstall it and then try to remove it

Comment: i don't know how to put image in comment else can send you screenshot as well